# Maxima not plotting

Tags: math, plot, maxima, wxmaxima

I've been trying to create a plot for a specific function, but I'm encountering an issue with the code. Here's the code I'm using:

```
kr: makelist(subst(C = k, ats), k, [0, 1, 2]);
[y/sqrt(2*e^x+1) = 0, y/sqrt(2*e^x+1) = 1, y/sqrt(2*e^x+1) = 2]
load(draw)$
y(x) := sqrt(2*e^x+1);
plot2d(y(x), [x, -6, 6], [y, -6, 6])
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
plot2d: nothing to plot.
```

I've tried troubleshooting this on my own without success.Can you please help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if there's something else going on, but anyway, Euler's number is `%e` instead of `e`, so in the above, you need to write `y(x) := sqrt(2*%e^x + 1)` or `y(x) := sqrt(2*exp(x) + 1)` instead of `y(x) := sqrt(2*e^x + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Figured out a solution, not sure how neat it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouFkw.png)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. We at SO appreciate your effort. To create maximum value for our users we avoid link-only answers. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) for details.